# Securing RMI calls using kerberos for SSO implementation

Tags: java, single-sign-on, rmi, kerberos, jaas

I am trying to implement kerberos SSO for a java swing application. The application uses RMI calls on t3 protocol. I dont want the user to enter user name and pwd instead want to access the windows userticket cache.

Possibilities I found on Google:

1. Modify the registry to add a keyword to access the ticketcache. This option is not approved by the client.
2. Use keytab files instead of ticket cache. Not a viable option because this cant be handled at the launch of application, keytab files need to be generated before the user tries to access the application.

Any insights on how to achieve SSO for java swing client on webstart will help. The applet is launched using a .jnlp file with the JAAS config and the initial context factory as parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you need the JAAS Kerberos login module, but it isn't clear how you plan to propagate the login information to the server, or indeed whether you want to do that at all.

Comment: I am generating the token using the native java api (jna) from the logged in windows user details. But currently weblogic 10.3.6 supports only username and password callback and i am unable to pass the token details to the server. Weblogic UsernamePasswordLoginModule uses the Authenticate.authenticate() method to pass the username and password in the jass login method.

Comment: I could find a way around to pass the username and token(credentials) to the weblogic authentication providers and login successfully.